# GPO applying for User config but not applying for Computer config

Tags: group-policy

I am applying a logon GPO to a Computer OU (with only computer objects within).

When I edit the policy User Configuration, it shows up in `gpresult -r`, but when I edit the policy Computer Configuration it doesn't show up in `gpresult -r`.

This was applied using `gpupdate/force`. Any idea why is this happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure, but this might help you:

1. In the Group Policy Microsoft Management Console (MMC), click Computer Configuration.
2. Locate Administrative Templates, click System, click Group Policy, and then enable the Loopback Policy option.

Try Merge Mode

https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/231287/loopback-processing-of-group-policy

Answer (score 1):

For the group policy object (GPO) in question, I suspect that the "GPO Status" might be set to "Computer Configuration settings disabled" currently, and hence the computer configuration (despite editing) is not coming into picture after group policy update!

Please confirm that for the said GPO, the "GPO Status" is set to Enabled ([as shown in the below screenshot](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/104008)), for allowing both User Configuration and Computer Configuration to come into effect. Please try after doing a fresh group policy update.

[image: GPO Status - Enabled]

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The GPO has been always Enabled as shown on your screen capture. It is really an odd behaviour

Comment: Hi @Tato. Do you suspect that any other GPO is overwriting this GPO (either based on inheritance or enforcement)? How are you checking the logon script's policy name on the client system?

Answer (score 0):

would rather comment something simple ("*run gpresult as admin*"), but I don't have the reputation (yet!)

I also like to "gpresult /h whatev.htm", then pull that page up and show all, to see stuff that's being applied; but, computer config stuff doesn't always show up for me, because I'm lazy, and sometimes I use a normal person's already logged in computer...

...so, to confirm computer config stuff, e.g. "power management" (in computer config > policies > admin templates > system), I just lookup said settings on a target machine (after running "gpupdate"), e.g. powershell "powercfg /list" and see that my asterisk changed (to what I picked in the gpo)

so, sometimes I just stay at my desk, where I'm logged in (and admin), and run powershell **as admin** (elevated), then:

```
PS C:\> enter-psSession computerNameHere
[computerNameHere]: PS C:\> gpresult /r /scope computer
```

note "applied group policy objects", where that would error out if you didn't run it as admin (or do our "gpresult /h whatev.htm" thing, but as admin, but then that file is on the local machine, so perhaps just grab it via file share?)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/572704)